# Schanuel topos an equivalent condition

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory, functors, monomorphisms

Let $I$ be the category of finite sets and monomorphisms.

The functor $P:I\rightarrow Sets$ is a sheaf for the atomic topology on $I^{op}$ iff $P$sends every morphism of $I$ to a monomorphism and $P$ preserves pullbacks.

I have no idea how to prove this...
I tried to show the pull back of a monomorphism is itself a monomorphism by the universal property...

Comment: "I tried to show the pull back of a monomorphism is itself a monomorphism by the universal property" - this is true and independent from the whole context, just a corollary of "limits commute with limits".

Comment: This is exercise 13 in chapter III of Maclane-Moerdijk. (Please make this transparent next time in case you took the exercise from there.) You can use (the dual of) Lemma 2 in that chapter, which characterizes sheaves w.r.t. the atomic topology. For example, it follows immediately that such a functor maps all morphisms to monomorphisms. Please try to use that Lemma and show your progress.